# reusing similar kind of views in django

Tags: django, django-views

```
class SupervisionView(MyBaseView, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'research/a1.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SupervisionView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['supervisions'] = list1
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'confirm_supervision1' in request.POST:
            return redirect(reverse_lazy('t_app:dept1', kwargs={'year': self.kwargs['year']}))


class SupervisionView2(MyBaseView, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'research/a2.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SupervisionView2, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['supervisions'] = list 2
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'confirm_supervision2' in request.POST:
            return redirect(reverse_lazy('t_app:dept2', kwargs={'year': self.kwargs['year']}))
```

I have some 20 odd functions doing the same thing again. only change is the context variable and redirect url in each view. What is the best way to compress this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a custom mixin:

```
class MyDRYMixin(object):
    context_variable = None
    post_variable = None
    redirect_name = None

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MyDRYMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.context_variable is not None:
            context['supervisions'] = self.context_variable
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.post_variable is not None and self.post_variable in request.POST:
            return redirect(reverse_lazy(self.redirect_name, kwargs={'year':self.kwargs['year']}
```

Then use that mixin in your views, making sure to define those three variables:

```
class SupervisionView(MyBaseView, MyDRYMixin, TemplateView):
    template_name = 'research/a1.html'
    context_variable = 'list1'
    post_variable = 'confirm_supervision1'
    redirect_name = 't_app:dept1'
```

You can set your variables equal to anything you want. When you mix your `MyDRYMixin` into a view, the values you provide in that view will be used rather than the values defined in the base mixin class. So in our example above, `context_variable == list1`. If we hadn't defined a `context_variable` in `SupervisionView` it would have defaulted to `None`, the value set in our base mixin.

If you want `context_variable` to reference the current user, for instance:

```
class SupervisionView(MyBaseView, MyDRYMixin, TemplateView):
    context_variable = self.request.user
    ...
```

(Edit: I made a mistake here! This should be done within `get_context_data` since we are accessing `self.request.user`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/)

Or maybe you have some kind of test you want to apply, like using one `context_variable` for authenticated users and a different one for unauthenticated users:

```
class SupervisionView(MyBaseView, MyDRYMixin, TemplateView):
    def set_context_variable(self):
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated():
            self.context_variable = 'foo'
        else:
            self.context_variable = 'bar'
```

Or:

```
class SupervisionView(MyBaseView, MyDRYMixin, TemplateView):
    def get_context_variable(self):
        if self.user.is_authenticated():
            return 'foo'
        return 'bar'

    context_variable = self.get_context_variable()
```

Comment: Excuse me for late response. The approach is wonderful only thing is that I need dynamic value. I mean, inside the SupervisionView 'context_variable' instead of 'list1' i need say request.user or calling a method elsewhere. How can that be done?

Comment: I've edited some info into my answer that I hope will help. Please let me know if I can clarify anything or if I've misunderstood what you're asking in any way. Thanks!

Comment: I tried exactly the same thing earlier like you posted:
`class SupervisionView(MyBaseView, MyDRYMixin, TemplateView):
    context_variable = self.request.user `

which resulted in NameError: name 'self' is not defined

(please excuse my very long delays in answer as there are serious difficulties to reply outside office hours due to lot of travel)

Comment: That's my mistake, sorry; I have edited my answer. Working with `self.request.user` should be done specifically in `get_context_data`, because that method will have access to `self`.

Comment: so, looking back at the question yet another time, we *can compress* the post section `def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.post_variable is not None and self.post_variable in request.POST:
            return redirect(reverse_lazy(self.redirect_name, kwargs={'year':self.kwargs['year']}` but get_context_data() method will remain the same. I think that much re-usability alone is possible. Am i right?

Comment: If I am understanding the question correctly then yes; sorry if I have confused the issue with my earlier mistake. The important thing about `get_context_data` is that `self.request.user` is available within that method, so if you want to work with that in your view `get_context_data` is a good place to do it.